# Text editing LinkedList vs List of lines

Tags: c#, .net, list, text, editor

I'm writing a text editor using C#, I know i'm just reinventing the wheel but it's a learning experience and something I want to do.

Right now I have a basic Text Document using something that resembles a Gap Buffer however I have to update my line buffer to hold the start of each line each time an edit is made to the buffer.

I am looking at creating another Text Document for testing using a list of lines and editing each line instead.

Now the question that I have is what would be the benefits of using a LinkedList vs a standard List?

Comment: By standard list I assume he means List<string>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A linked list of lines will be fast to insert new lines or delete lines, and fast to move down (and up if you have a doubly-linked list) from a specific line by a small number of lines, and fast to move to the start of the document. To move quickly to the end of the document you will also need to store the end of the linked list. It is relatively slow to go to a specific line number though, as you will have to start from the beginning and iterate over the lines, although this shouldn't be a problem unless your documents have very many lines.

An ordinary list is fast to move to a specific line number but slow to add or remove any line except at the end as the entire buffer will need to be copied each time a line is inserted or deleted.

I would prefer a linked list over an array based list for the purposes of editing large documents. In either case you may have problems if the document contains any extremely long lines as strings are immutable and changing each character will be slow.

Comment: Thanks, as for editing each line, I would probably use a StringBuilder instead of a String for editing, replacing text in the line.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a one string per line array. Arrays are often faster or equal to update then linked list because they have a much better cache locality then linked list and for a single 1st level cache miss you can move already a few dozens pointer items in an array. I would say for everything less then 10000 items just use an array of pointers.

If your edited text are small (like hand written source code files) it is the way to go. A lot of the meta information you need for state of the art text editing can be split very well into "beginning of a line" points. Most importantly syntax highlighting.

Also error lines, breakpoints, profiling infos, code coverage markers, all of them work on a line. It's the native structure of source code text and in same cases also for literature text (if you write a text processor and not a source code editor) but in that case your need to take a paragraph as a unit.

If i ever find the time to redesign my editor i will add different buffer implementations because on larger texts the overhead of all the line info data (it's about 80 byte per line on a 32bit system) is significant. Then a gap buffer model is better, it is also much better if you don't have lines at all for example when displaying binary files in hex mode.

And finally a third buffer model is required when you allow a user to open large files. It's funny to see marketing bullshit (free open source is surprisingly worse here) about unlimited file size editing and once you open a 400 MB log file, the whole system becames unresponsive. You need a buffer model here which is not loading the whole file into the buffer first.

Comment: Thanks, the editor i'm building will be used for editing source files, mostly nothing over a couple hundred kilobytes, although I was also looking into memory mapped files for being able to load large documents, but it's not necessary at this point in time.